# Returning a value from a bash function

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a function which returns 1 if the number is a valid ten digit number:

```
valNum()
{
    flag=1
    if [[ $1 != [1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] ]]; then
        echo "Invalid Number"
        flag=0
    fi
    return $flag
}
```

It is getting called by:

```
if [[ $(valNum $num) -eq 1 ]]; then
      #do something
fi
```

The function is working fine if the number is valid but is showing syntax error if input a invalid number.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

@choroba's answer is correct, however this example might be clearer:

```
valNum $num
valNumResult=$? # '$?' is the return value of the previous command
if [[ $valNumResult -eq 1 ]]
then
  : # do something
fi
```

This example is a little longer (setting `$valNumResult` then querying that value), but more-explicitly describes what happens: that `valNum()` returns a value, and that value can be queried and tested.

P.S. Please do yourself a favor and return `0` for `true` and non-zero for `false`.  That way you can use the return value to indicate "why we failed" in the failure case.

Answer (score 8):

Functions in bash can only return exit codes. The command substitution, conversely, is used to get the standard output of a command or function. Therefore, to check the returned flag, you do not need the substitution:

```
if valNum "$num" ; then
    # ...
fi
```

But, for it to work, you should return 0 if the number is valid, and 1 if it is not (exit code 0 means no error).

Comment: I dont get it. In the example 24.7 in http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/complexfunct.html the function is returning the max value and not the exit code. Though your suggestion is working but I am not able to understand why it is working

Comment: since your test is to find out if the input is a valid 10-digit integer or not, i.e. true or false, the function returns either 0 or 1.  choroba's example works because `if valnum "$num"` is equivalent to `if valnum "$num" = 0` i.e. "if it is true".  basic rule of thumb in sh scripting is that 0 = true/success, non-zero = false/error.

Comment: BTW, that "Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide" isn't a very good guide - it's wrong about a lot of things and encourages some poor scripting practices.  the Bash FAQ at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ is much better resource.

Comment: see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12236/best-resources-to-learn-bash-scripting

Comment: your function is failing because it is echo-ing the string "Invalid Number", and you then doing a numeric comparison between that string and the number 1 with `if [[ $(valNum $num) -eq 1 ]]`

Answer (score 6):

You cannot return an arbitrary result from a shell function. You can only return a status code which is an integer between 0 and 255. (While you can pass a larger value to `return`, it is truncated modulo 256.) The value must be 0 to indicate success and a different value to indicate failure; by convention you should stick to error codes between 1 and 125, as higher values have a special meaning (bad external command for 126 and 127, killed by a signal for higher values).

Since you are returning a yes-or-no result here, a status code is appropriate. Since `flag` seems to indicate a success or failure, you should use the conventional values of 0 for success and 1 for failure (the opposite of what you wrote). You can then use your function directly in an if statement.

```
valNum ()
{
  local flag=0
  if [[ $1 != [1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] ]]; then
    echo 1>&2 "Invalid Number"
    flag=1
  fi
  return $flag
}
if valNum "$num"; then
  #do something
fi
```

If you need to discriminate between failure codes, call the function directly. Immediately after it returns, the failure code is available in `$?`. You can then check it with a case statement:

```
valNum "$num"
case $? in …
```

If you need to use the status code later, save it into another variable before `$?` is overwritten by the next command.

```
valNum "$num"
valNum_status=$?
```

What you wrote didn't work because the command substitution `$(…)` expands to the output of the function, which in your code is either the error message or empty, never `1`.

If you need to pass more information than a status code allows out of a shell functions, you have two possibilities:

- Print some text on standard output, and call the function in a command substitution: `$(valNum "$num")`
- Assign to one or more variable inside the function and read those variables later.

Answer (score 2):

I've had conflicting results in this area myself.  Here are results from my empirical experiments.  Firstly, some '*theory*' about bash or *nix commands:

- SUCCESS == **0** ... viz. no error status code)
- FAIL          != 0 ...... some status code

Example:

```
if  ls -lt /nonexistantdir
then 
    echo "found"
else
    echo "FAIL"
fi
#
echo
ls -lt /nonexistantdir; echo "status = $?"
echo "status = $?"
```

Output:

```
ls: cannot access '/nonexistantdir': No such file or directory
FAIL... 

ls: cannot access '/nonexistantdir': No such file or directory
status = 2
```

As shown, the `ls` command returns status code = 2.  When you try a valid directory, the status is zero(**0**).  Not the same as almost all other languages.

***rule* #1** -- Make ...

- TRUE   == **0**
- FALSE != 0

We must remember that we are *testing* error codes in a Bash `if` statement.  I set-up constants, or you can use shell `true` or `false` commands.

```
TRUE=0
FALSE=1

#  valid number function
#
valNum()
{
    flag=$TRUE

    if [[ $1 != [1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] ]]; then
        echo "Invalid Number"
        flag=$FALSE
    fi
    return $flag
}

#    later on ...
#
if validNum Abc 
then
    echo "Lucky number"
else
    echo "Not lucky."
fi
```

and output:

```
Invalid Number
Not lucky.
```

However, I suggest you give any '*up-vote*' @Gilles because his answer is the correct one.  I just wanted to get the simplistic-side down on ePaper.

Just one other thing, the **`test`** command.  This looks like:

```
[[ some-expression ]];
```

Most of the time.  And for example:

```
$ test 1
$ echo "result = $?"
result = 0
$ test 0
$ echo "result = $?"
result = 0
```

Zero(0) being ***true***.  Why?  Well the man page says that a single argument is '*true*' when it is NOT-NULL.

references:

- [Bash Pitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#if_.5Bgrep_foo_myfile.5D)
- [if man page](https://ss64.com/bash/if.html)